# possible reasons for excessive memory consumption when instantiating a generic list of a managed VisualC++ type vs C# type?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, generics, memory-leaks

I've spent the last couple of days attempting to pinpoint the source of a memory leak on a .NET application I'm responsible for maintaining.

The application is mostly written in C#, but some parts reference a Visual C++ assembly. The memory leaks seem to center around the parts of the code that interact with the types defined in the Visual C++ assembly.

It could very well be that the Visual C++ assembly is using unmanaged resources that are not being disposed properly, but I'm intrigued by the fact that merely initializing a generic list of Visual C++ types increases memory usage (perfmon.exe: Process|Private Bytes) significantly, even if no elements are added to the list.

Please see the following sample code:

```
//defined in a referenced Visual CPP assembly
public class ref VisualCPPType
{
    private:
        String ^ a;
        String ^ b;

    public:
        VisualCppType(String ^ a, String ^ b)
        {
            this->a = a;
            this->b = b;
        }
}
//defined in the CSharp assembly
public class CSharpType
{
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public CSharpType(String a, String b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
//defined in the CSharp assembly
public class ListWrapper
{
    public List<VisualCPPType> _visualCppElementList;
    public List<CSharpType> _cSharpElementList;

    public ListWrapper(bool trueToInitVisualCppListOnly_falseToInitCSharpListOnly)
    {
        if (trueToInitVisualCppListOnly_falseToInitCSharpListOnly)
        {
            //Process|Working Set - Private -> increases by ~5000K
            //Process|Private Bytes -> increases by ~5000K
            //.NET CLR Memory|Bytes In All Heaps -> remains constant
            _visualCppElementList = new List<VisualCPPType>();
        }
        else
        {
            //Process|Working Set - Private -> increases by ~750K
            //Process|Private Bytes -> increases by ~500K
            //.NET CLR Memory|Bytes In All Heaps -> remains constant
            _cSharpElementList = new List<CSharpType>();
        }
    }
}
//defined in the CSharp assembly
public class EntryPoint
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        //a utility class that can be used to obtain the same data displayed by perfmon.exe
        MemoryMonitor monitor = MemoryMonitor.NewMonitor();

        ListWrapper list = new ListWrapper(Boolean.parse(args[0]);

        monitor.PrintMemoryDiff();
    }
}
```

As I noted in the comments, the mere act of instantiating a generic list of a Visual C++ element type appears to be a much more expensive operation than instantiating a generic list of a similar C# type.

Can someone please explain this behavior? And if it seems like this could be one of the possible causes of the memory leak, offer some hints as to how I could go about fixing it?

Comment: so does your minimal example exhibit the leak?

Comment: It does exhibit the same increase in memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module initializer in the C++/CLI assembly will run the very first time you instantiate a type from a C++/CLI assembly.  You'll slurp the virtual memory required to map that assembly into the process.  And kick-start the CRT, a pretty big DLL (msvcr110d.dll is 1,657 KB msvcp110d.dll is 821 KB).  And get the private unmanaged heap created.  Lots of nitty-gritty small allocations beyond this.

Sure, you'll see this back in the Private Bytes value.  This is of course not a problem.